# цикл for cчетчик +10

Tags: php

Есть такой цикл

```
for ($i=0; $i < 50; $i+10) {
    echo "$i </br>";
}
```

Происходит зацикливание, так как **$i** не увеличивается на 10.

Если ставить **$i++** то работает.

В цикле можно только инкремент и декремент использовать?

Comment: `$i+10` не имеет смысла в данном контексте, замените на `$i+=10` (`$i=$i+10`)

Comment: `$i = $i + 10`.....или `$i += 10`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно, почему оно должно увеличиваться? Хотите менять переменную, меняйте как положено: `$i += 10`. Особенность оператора инкремента `++` в том, что он как раз таки меняет саму переменную и почти аналогичен записи `$i += 1`(есть отличия при участие в выражениях, см. постинкремент и прединкремент).

Answer (score 2):

Вы не наращиваете переменную цикла, исправьте:

```
for ($i=0; $i < 50; $i+=10) {
    echo "$i </br>";
}
```